# Can you view someones twitter page that isnt my own as a json api?

Tags: json, api, authentication, twitter, profile

Can you view someones twitter page that isnt my own as a json api?
From what I've seen you need a authentication key, anyone know a way that works?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the contents of another user's profile, and you can retrieve a list of their tweets.  However, it is necessary for your application to authenticate with Twitter via OAuth;  third-party applications cannot authenticate with a user's username and password.

You'll want to start [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth).  It may seem complicated, but don't be discouraged.  Your best bet will be to find an existing Twitter library that handles authentication for you.  This problem has been solved for many languages and development platforms.  Don't re-do what other people have already done. :)